# Correct way to access properties of class instances from inside a class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, class, generics, methods

Why does this work:

```
class ListNode<T> {
  data: T | null;
  next: ListNode<T> | null;

  constructor(val?: T, next?: ListNode<T>) {
    this.data = val ? val : null;
    this.next = next ? next : null;
  }
}

class LinkedList {
  head: ListNode<string> | null;
  currentSize: number = 0;

  constructor(head?: ListNode<string>) {
    this.head = head ? head : null;
  }

  addFirst(val: string) {
    const node: ListNode<string> = new ListNode(val);
    node.next = this.head;
    this.head = node;
    this.currentSize += 1
  }
}
const myList = new LinkedList();
myList.addFirst("foo");
```

But this doesn't:

```
class ListNode<T> {
  data: T | null;
  next: ListNode<T> | null;

  constructor(val?: T, next?: ListNode<T>) {
    this.data = val ? val : null;
    this.next = next ? next : null;
  }
}

class LinkedList<ListNode> {
  head: ListNode | null;
  currentSize: number = 0;

  constructor(head?: ListNode) {
    this.head = head ? head : null;
  }

  addFirst(newNode: ListNode) {
    // Property 'next' does not exist on type 'ListNode'. ts(2339)
    newNode.next = this.head;
    this.head = newNode;
    this.currentSize += 1;
  }
}


const myNode = new ListNode("foo");
const myList = new LinkedList();

myList.addFirst(myNode);
```

Both solutions result in working JS, but the second solution shows the TS error `Property 'next' does not exist on type 'ListNode'. ts(2339)`. I understand the `next` of `newNode` would be null, but TS is telling me that `next` **property** doesn't exist, even though it's defined in the class `ListNode`.

And if I'm missing something simple to make the second option work, which way would be best? I think the second one because it would allow for nodes with next pointers rather than just one node at a time (after implementing `tail` pointers of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is `LinkedList<ListNode>` ??

Shouldnt it be class `LinkedList<T>`??

```
export class LinkedList<T> {
    head: ListNode<T> | null;
    currentSize: number = 0;

    constructor(head?: ListNode<T>) {
        this.head = head ? head : null;
    }

    addFirst(newNode: ListNode<T>) {
        // Property 'next' does not exist on type 'ListNode'. ts(2339)
        newNode.next = this.head;
        this.head = newNode;
        this.currentSize += 1;
    }
}
```

Then you can do the following

```
myNode = new ListNode(2);
myList = new LinkedList<number>(); <<------Specifying the generic type
myList.addFirst(this.myNode);
```

or

```
myNode = new ListNode("test");
myList = new LinkedList<string>(); <<------Specifying the generic type
myList.addFirst(this.myNode);
```

**Additionally to answer your question why the latter code section doesn't work where `LinkedList<ListNode>`.**

Because when you specify `LinkedList<ListNode>`, here `ListNode` is a generic class type and not the a type of `ListNode` class you've specify above. Just like `LinkedList<T>` where `T` is a type of class.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your type is being overridden

```
class LinkedList<ListNode> { // <- it's this ListNode
    addFirst(newNode: ListNode) {
        //            ^?
        // (type parameter) ListNode in LinkedList<ListNode>

        // Property 'next' does not exist on type 'ListNode'. ts(2339)
        newNode.next
    }
}
```

You didn't say that node is a ListNode you defined before like

```
class LinkedList<ListNode1 extends ListNode<any>> { // <- it's this ListNode
    addFirst(newNode: ListNode1) {
        //            ^?
        // (type parameter) ListNode1 in LinkedList<ListNode1 extends ListNode<any>>
        newNode.next
        //      ^?
        // (property) ListNode<any>.next: ListNode<any> | null
    }
}
```